# The same linux permission characters but with different numbers

Tags: linux, permissions, directory

I have two different folders in my directory with the following permissions:

file x:
`drwxr-xr-x 2` , file y: `drwxr-xr-x 5`. What is the permission difference between these two folders? why one has number 2 and the other 5?

Comment: @steeldriver , it's not clear yet: `what constitutes a "link" here varies.` What does it mean number of links?

Comment: @steeldriver, yes it's .. thanks